# How to represent "A" class if "B" class is present

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-selectors

I am wondering if there is a way to represent class A if class B is present.  In my case I want "container_inner2" to have a padding of 0px if "promo_move" is there.

I know there are combinators to represent class B if A is present, but I can't figure out if want I need is possible.

Here's the HTML and the current CSS -

HTML

```
<div class="container_inner">
<div class="container_inner2 clearfix">
<div class="promo_move">
Some content....
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CURRENT CSS

```
.container_inner .container_inner2 {
padding: 30px;
}
```

Again, I would like container_inner and container_inner2 to have 0 padding if promo_move is there.

If this isn't possible with css, any other solutions are welcome. (This is on a Wordpress site.  All pages can have the 30px padding except one.)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: you can't with css ... you can if promo is before but not after

Comment: Your best friend will be javascript and jQuery with this problem

Comment: How about giving `margin: -30px` to the `.promo_move` instead of giving `padding: 0px` to `.container_inner2` ? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4S6PJ/).

Answer (score 1):

Your description is very misleading. You mean that you want to style the `.container_inner` and `.container_inner2` elements if they both have a `.promo_move` descendant.

That is not possible with CSS. Since this is on a WordPress site, you can use jQuery's `.has()` function to filter the elements before you decide whether to apply the padding, like so:

```
$('.container_inner, .container_inner2').has('.promo_move').css('padding', 0);
```